# How to Pass two Different Number Formats in decimal.ToString()

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have two different queries for which I have

```
(535.00).ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Configuration.UICulture));
```

but what I want is if there is `0` after decimal I don't want to show `decimal` digit and if there is something else for example `535.50` then only I want to show the decimal so for that I am out with the solution `decimal.ToString("G29")` and now I am not able to do that since I am already using culture format for `$` sign and the value is converted into `string`.

So, I want to use both the formats in `string.ToDecimal("G29")` and
`string.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Configuration.UICulture))` since I want the resultant value to be either `535$` or `535.50$`.

You can either suggest me how to use multiple decimal to string formatted or you can suggest me some better solution if you have. I will appreciate your answer.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure you can solve this using just format strings or culture info objects. A rather naive solution would be `.Replace(".00$", "$")` but I don't like it.

Comment: Something like ... https://dotnetfiddle.net/SVhV5w ? Or https://dotnetfiddle.net/Aof5mG ?

Comment: No but I need to use culture not hardcoded "$" to maintain consistency in the code

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `n2` numeric format to get two decimal digits, then remove any `.00` part by making sure to use the right decimal separator and finally add the currency symbol.

```cs
decimal input = 535.00m; // or 535.50m
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Configuration.UICulture);
string nullDecimal = numberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator + "00";
string output = input.ToString("n2", cultureInfo).Replace(nullDecimal, "") +
    cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;
```

Displays `535$` or `535.50$`.

You could also use the currency format directly

```cs
string output = input.ToString("c2", cultureInfo).Replace(nullDecimal, "")
```

but this will put the $ sign before the number I think.

Note that `n2` produces thousands (group) separators (e.g. `1,535.50$`). Use `f2` instead, if you don't want this.

The `c` format produces as many digits as specified in `NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyDecimalDigits`. So, you may want to use this one and to get the number of 0 decimals to remove dynamically

```cs
decimal[] inputs = { 1535.00m, 1535.50m };
foreach (decimal input in inputs) {
    var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Configuration.UICulture);
    NumberFormatInfo numberFormat = cultureInfo.NumberFormat;
    string nullDecimal = numberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator +
        new string('0', numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits);
    string output = input.ToString("c", cultureInfo).Replace(nullDecimal, "");

    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

For en-US, this prints:

```
$1,535
$1,535.50
```

for ja-JP:

```
¥1,535
¥1,536
```

Comment: The currency format controls the punctuation of the number (commas or decimal points or spaces) the currency symbol and the location of the currency symbol based on the culture. Some cultures put the currency symbol at the end of the number, so using the currency format would definitely be the safer thing to use.

Comment: @TJRockefeller, yes. See my final solution.